# visnetwork gradient by degree of group

Tags: r, plot, visnetwork

I am using visIgraph to draw a network graph in R. By the way,I want to put the darkest gradient in the group with the largest number of nodes, the lightest color with the least number of nodes.

Here is my sample code.

```
dat2<-data.frame(from=c("A",'B','C','E','F','H','J','K','L',
                        "M",'N','P','O','R','S','U'),
                 to=c("B",'D','D','G','G','I','I','I',"I",'N','O','Q','S','T','T','T'))
dat3 <- data.frame(source=dat2$from, dest=dat2$to)
g <- graph.data.frame(dat3)

clust <- clusters(g)
V(g)$color <- ifelse(clust$membership== as.numeric(names(which.max(table(clust$membership)))), "darkblue", "lightblue")

visIgraph(igraph=g,idToLabel=TRUE,layout = "layout_nicely")
```

[image]

I want the graph to look like this when I apply a gradient.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
clust <- clusters(g)

V(g)$color <- ifelse(clust$membership== as.numeric(names(which.max(table(clust$membership))) ), "darkblue", "lightblue")

visIgraph(igraph=g,idToLabel=TRUE,layout = "layout_nicely")
```

**1. Edit** Multiple groups and coloring order

had to add a sorting to get the coloring in the right order according to group size

```
clust <- clusters(g)

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("lightblue", "darkblue"))

colorder <- setNames(c(as.numeric(names(sort(table(clust$membership))))), c(colfunc(clust$no)))

V(g)$color <- names(colorder)[match(clust$membership,colorder)]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answers. it's good working. So, Instead of using the max function,what if there are several groups? I have to 10 groups apply. Do I have to enter each color?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. you genius. thank you so much